# Hibernate doesn't allow not unique records even when unique is false

Tags: hibernate, spring-orm

I have a databse with users and their passwords.
when i launch my app i create some users with roles and store them into database. 
My user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNAME",  nullable = false,  unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "ENABLED", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled = true;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<>();
...getters and setters
```

and userRole entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    private String role;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME")
    private User user;
```

column role is unique=false by default, but when i add userA with roles: admin,user and then userB with roles: user, record userB - user overwrites record userA - user. Can someone point what is my mistake?

i'm using hibernate 5 + spring 5

Comment: It has nothing to do with Hibernate disallowing something. It's a bug in your code. Post the code reproducing this problem, and explain it clearly. `UserRole.role` is the ID of your entity. So it uniquely identifies an entity, by definition of ID. If you expect two UserRoles with the same ID, then your expectations are incorrect. An ID is always unique. That's the very definition of an ID.

Comment: Write it as an answer so i an mark it as once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ID is, by definition, unique. That's what uniquely identifies an entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you saves a role for userB as you have mapping for User in UserRole and CascadeType.ALL, after saving it overrides USERNAME of role `user` in your db. Do you really need mapping on User in UserRole? If it not neccessary, I think you should remove it from UserRole entity and leavy only name of role. For example, it is possible to map role in user like

```
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"))
    @Column(name = "role")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;
```